# How to correctly take a Date object passed with state in React into datepicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing, datepicker, timestamp

I'm using DatePicker with my react app. I pass an object which contains a date field from one component to another via location.state. This is an editing component, where I can change the values of these fields. But the console swears with invalid time exception. I read I should do something with parseISO but still it does nothing. How to properly use it? (settings is a this.state field)

```
...
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'
import { parseISO, format } from 'date-fns'
...

            <DatePicker
              name="saleDateFrom"
              selected={parseISO(settings.saleDateFrom)}
              onChange={this.handleChangeFrom}
              dateFormat="MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Date.parse(settings.saleDateFrom)` to get the time since epoch.

If you need it as a data object.

`new Date(Date.parse(settings.saleDateFrom))`

Answer (score 1):

```
   <DatePicker
          name="saleDateFrom"
          selected={new Date(settings.saleDateFrom)}
          onChange={this.handleChangeFrom}
          dateFormat="MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"
        />
```

This will take care of your issues. react-datepicker expects date as javascript Date objects